# Randomly display either key or value from dictionary; followed by it's corresponding paired item

Tags: python, dictionary, random

This is my first post. I'm hoping someone would kindly help me.

I'm looking to create a program, to at random display either a dictionary key or value, then following user input such as a key pressed to then show the key or values corresponding item.

A dictionary will store values that represent some letters in the alphabet and their corresponding numerical position.

```
alphabet = {'1':'A','2':'B','3':'C','4':'D'}
```

This code will give the user a number, then after pressing return it will display the corresponding letter in the alphabet.

```
random_selection = choice(list(alphabet))
print('Guess corresponding value', random_selection)
    input('Press return to see corresponding value')
    print(alphabet[random_selection])
```

How can I code the program to randomly pick either a number or letter? For example, it may instead show the letter B, then 2 once the user has pressed return.

I would next create a loop so the program runs continuously but I'm confident I can already do this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to perform lookups in both directions i.e. find keys by their values too, a dictionary is not the way to go, since it is bad for that inverse lookup. I would probably store this `alphabet` as a list of 2-tuples instead, then pick one of them using the `choice` function and then pick either the first or the second element of the tuple randomly again (e.g. using that same `choice` function.

You can convert the dictionary to a list of tuples like this:

```py
list(alphabet.items())
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of using `choice` a second time, you could do this:

```py
from random import choice, sample

alphabet = {'1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '4': 'D'}

...
pair = choice(list(alphabet.items()))
key, value = sample(pair, k=2)
print('Guess corresponding value', key)
input('Press return to see corresponding value')
print(value)
```

The [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function returns a randomly shuffled sub-sequence of length `k`.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a possible implementation of my first idea, as requested:

```py
from random import choice

alphabet = {'1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '4': 'D'}

...
pair = choice(list(alphabet.items()))
key = choice(pair)
value = pair[0] if key == pair[1] else pair[1]
print('Guess corresponding value', key)
input('Press return to see corresponding value')
print(value)
```

I hope it is clear, why this solution is less elegant.

Comment: Thank you. This achieves what I needed to do. Would you mind providing some code in your original solution also please? Converting to a list of 2-tuples and then using choice? 

I'd be most grateful. I haven't covered sample function, so an alternative would be helpful.

Comment: The edit I made was supposed to indicate that I consider my initial idea to be sub-optimal. If you use choice, you then need to check which element of your tuple it **didn't** pick, which is possible of course, but _wonky_ and very much inelegant IMO. If you insist to see it, I can provide a possible implementation, but I don't think it would be a good solution.

Comment: I agree, this is a much better solution and your code is much simpler than I thought it. Would you mind providing some code for the original idea? I'd be really interested to see and it will help me develop my understanding further,

Comment: @nowmakeshift0 I appended the code you requested to my answer. Glad I could help. Would appreciate the upvote. :)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I did try to upvote but as a new user my reputation is too low. I'll be engaging more actively now in these forums and we'll hopefully cross paths again.